# How would one get a list of installed codecs?

Tags: c#, windows, codec

I'm developing a software that helps detect  problems of customers who watching TV throw the internet.  I need to know what codecs do they have.  How can I get a list of the customer's codecs?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is sample code [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391078(VS.85).aspx). This shouldn't be too hard to convert to C#.

There is example code from someone who has done it, and tested on Windows XP [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/CCodecList.aspx).

Followup: [the example MSDN code has moved to here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743771%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and it now shows Audio and Video codecs separately.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. it gives only the video's codec not the audio.
do you have any more ideas?

thanks a lot
Itay

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but a workaround: Install the needed codecs whether they have them or not (ie, [K-lite](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)). This will fix any missing, corrupted or out-of-date codecs. The basic pack (which is really not that basic) is only 5Mb which is chicken feed for someone with the bandwidth required for IP-TV.